# C++ pre-runtime symbolic differentiation

Tags: c++, templates, symbolic-math

Suppose I want to implement a gradient descent based optimizer of some function f(x),
which is a combination of simple functions: +,*,sin,cos (leaving out / for simplicity)

Is there a way, using templates to symbolically calculate the derivative and make a function f'(x)
in C++, then use the function and its gradient at runtime to optimize it.

I'm comfortable with symbolic mathematics, so that isn't the focus of the question.
I could write a parser and input the function as a string, expanding it dynamically at runtime, but especially for more complex functions, this is liable to be slow.

If there's a way to produce the function at compile time, that would be awesome.

Comment: you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates. however syntax will be a awkward if you are not accustomed to it, you can make it somewhat better by `constexpr` objects and operators.

Comment: Maybe you can create your own preprocessor program? Something similar as described here for [Java math expressions](https://github.com/axkr/java_codegen)

Comment: You might want to search for "automatic differentiation" on the web, and cppad in particular.